# Simulate absolute path on XAMPP Server

Tags: php, xampp

I am currently working on a server, and I want to work locally on it. So I copied everything.

The problem is that in the code on the server, I include files with absolute paths like this:

```
include /home/root/html_folder/file.php
```

I want that this /home/root/html_folder to redirect to

```
/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/myApp.
```

Is there an easy way to do so?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option one - Relative paths

Relative paths are fairly simple in PHP.

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);

// Shorter constant
define('DS', 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR');

// To display the path:
echo $root;

// To include a file, no matter where your project is
include $root.DS.'file.php';
```

### Option two - Symbolic Links

Since you have pointed out that all your files use absolute paths the above is not a solution for you.

You could try using symbolic links.

Read about them [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Note: I would still like to suggest making your includes relative. This will save you lots of trouble in the future.

### Option three - Mounting

You can also mount your remote filesystem and work on it directly without having to use ssh and work in a console.

You can install SHFS on Mac OSX. You will need to download FUSE and SSHFS from the [osxfuse](http://osxfuse.github.io/) site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is very useful, but hard to implement for me as I have lots of files using absolute path on my server :s. I will think about this method next time I build a website.

Comment: <code>dirname(__FILE__)</code> can be shortened with <code>__DIR__</code>

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: yes, i used to work directly on it with ssh. I decided to work locally because it is more convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much. Option 3 is the best for me as I cannot write a symlink in /home folder on my mac :-)

Comment: Important notice for option one: you need to put `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` without quotes or it will be used as a string instead of the constant that would give you the separator.

Comment: And if you want to go one level down using the option one, you can use the function realpath: `realpath(__DIR__ .DS .'..')`